# Analysis of algorithms (complexity)

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

How are algorithms analyzed? What makes quicksort have an `O(n^2)` worst-case performance while merge sort has an `O(n log(n))` worst-case performance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a topic for an entire semester.  Ultimately we are talking about the upper bound on the number of operations that must be completed before the algorithm finishes as a function of the size of the input.  We do not include the coeffecients (ie 10N vs 4N^2) because for N large enough, it doesn't matter anymore.

How to prove what the big-oh of an algorithm is can be quite difficult.  It requires a formal proof and there are many techniques. Often a good adhoc way is to just count how many passes on the data the algorithm makes.  For instance, if your algorithm has nested for loops, then for each of N items you must operate N times.  That would generally be O(N^2).

As to merge sort, you split the data in half over and over.  That takes log2(n). And for each split you make a pass on the data, which gives N log(n).

quick sort is a bit trickier because in the average case it is also n log (n).  You have to imagine what happens if your partition splits the data such that every time you get only one element on one side of the partition.  Then you will need to split the data n times instead of log(n) times which makes it N^2.  The advantage of quicksort is that it can be done in place, and that we usually get closer to N log(n) performance.

Answer (score 1):

Both [quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) and [merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) split the array into two, sort each part recursively, then combine the result. Quicksort splits by choosing a "pivot" element and partitioning the array into smaller or greater then the pivot. Merge sort splits arbitrarily and then merges the results in linear time. In both cases a single step is O(n), and if the array size halves each time this would give a logarithmic number of steps. So we would expect O(n log(n)).

However quicksort has a worst case where the split is always uneven so you don't get a number of steps proportional to the logarithmic of n, but a number of steps proportional to n. Merge sort splits exactly into two halves (or as close as possible) so it doesn't have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. This is introductory analysis of algorithms course material.
2. An operation is defined (ie, multiplication) and the analysis is performed in terms of either space or time.
3. This operation is counted in terms of space or time. Typically analyses are performed as Time being the dependent variable upon Input Size.

Example pseudocode:

```
foreach $elem in @list

   op();

endfor
```

There will be *n* operations performed, where *n* is the size of `@list`. Count it yourself if you don't believe me.

To analyze quicksort and mergesort requires a decent level of what is known as mathematical sophistication. Loosely, you solve a discrete differential equation derived from the recursive relation.

Comment: The addition of how the operation is counted is important. I have upped the score on this 'answer'.

Answer (score 0):

- Quick sort has many variants depending on pivot selection
- Let's assume we always select 1st item in the array as a pivot

If the input array is sorted then Quick sort will be only a kind of selection sort!
Because you are not really dividing the array.. you are only picking first item in each cycle

On the other hand merge sort will always divide the input array in the same manner, regardless of its content!

Also note: the best performance in divide and conquer when divisions length are -nearly- equal !

Answer (score 0):

Analysing algorithms is a painstaking effort, and it is error-prone. I would compare it with a question like, how much chance do I have to get dealt two aces in a bridge game. One has to carefully consider all possibilities and must not overlook that the aces can arrive in any order.

So what one does for analysing those algorithms is going through an actual pseudo code of the algorithm and add what result a worst case situation would have. In the following I will paint with a large brush.

For quicksort one has to choose a pivot to split the set. In a case of dramatic bad luck the set splits in a set of n-1 and a set of 1 each time, for n steps, where each steps means inspecting n elements. This arrive at N^2

For merge sort one starts  by splitting the sequence into in order sequences. Even in the worst case that means at most n sequences. Those can be combined two by two, then the larger sets are combined two by two etc. However those (at most) n/2 first combinations deal with extremely small subsets, and the last step deals with subsets that have about size n, but there is just one such step. This arrives at N.log(N)